# TeX input mode and subscript

Tags: input-method, utf-8, tex

I'm a bit lost on what I can use the TeX input mode for. What I'd like to achieve is a mathematical notation like ∑ᵢ₌₁ᴺ ∑ⱼ₌₁ᴹ in pure UTF text and it seems to mostly work, i.e. `\sum _ i _ = _ 1` works, but `\sum_t` gives ∑ₜ which I guess means that the symbol _t is not supported by the current (what exactly?). When I try `M-x describe-input-method Ret TeX` I also see that `_t` is not supported. So, is this a limitation with a particular font, UTF itself, my computer or moon phase? And is there a solution? I tried both on my computer, with Mac OS X and a remote server, both seem to miss similar subscript letters.

Comment: The result of `\sum_t` that  you've pasted here seems to include a subscript t (which is what I'd expect the output to look like). How does it look like in Emacs? Also, how does `describe-input-method` tell you that `_t` is not supported?

Comment: yes, what I  wan't is subscript t. Emacs shows me a box with four numbers inside, 20 on the upper and 9c on the lower. If I try to paste it here, it gives empty box. `describe-input-method` shows the same, that _t corresponds to a box with strange numbers inside. However, _i and _j are treated as proper underscores.

Comment: 209c (8348 in decimal) is the codepoint of the character subscript t, so Emacs correctly generates the character but just cannot display it. (In your question I see the copy-pasted subscript t correctly). The fault is (most probably) with the font. The solution would be to use a different font. It seems, though, that your browser has trouble displaying the characters as well. (For instance, view: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin_and_Greek_tables ).

Comment: You can change the default font with `M-x customize-face RET default RET`. I don't know what fonts are available on your computer, so I can't make any real recommendations.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63283/how-to-find-browse-fonts-that-include-certain-rare-characters-unicode-internat might help you. On my computer (Ubuntu 16.04), in Emacs, the "subscript t" character is displayed with the pre-installed `DejaVu Sans Mono` font.

Comment: @aplaiceThanks, the wiki link you showed has the similar problem displaying the `subscript t`. I've tried several fonts in Emacs now without luck and considering my browser has the similar problem, then I guess the problem is not Emacs related but something with system fonts instead. I do not seem to have `DejaVu Sans Mono` on my mac.